# Incompatible SQL Server version found with Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-data-tools

Recently upgraded to SQL server 2014 from SQL 2008 R2 and SQL server object explorer in Visual Studio 2010 professional is no longer recognising my 2014 database.

When trying to add a database I get this error

```
"Incompatible SQL Server version found"
```

[MSDN blog about SSDT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/01/30/ssdt-and-visual-studio-versions.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20ssdtblog%20%28SQL%20Server%20Developer%20Tools%20Team%20Blog%29)

I tried installing SSDT 2014 for VS 2012 hoping that VS 2010 problem will get some how resolved, but not to avail.

The normal server explorer is able to connect to the SQL2014 instance, but there are a lot of stored procedures and the interface is a bit slow.

The blog suggests to upgrade to VS 2012 or later version.

But is there any way to stay in VS 2010 and access SQL 2014 with SQL server object explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: I think you will need to switch to a newer version of Visual Studio

Long answer:

1. This announcement promotes an update for VS 2012 & 2013 for a new version of SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) compatible with SQL Server 2014: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/03/25/sql-server-data-tools-for-sql-server-2014-is-available.aspx
2. This link states that with the release of VS 2013, they will no longer be updating VS 2010: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/01/30/ssdt-and-visual-studio-versions.aspx

From those MSDN links, my conclusion is that you'll need to get a newer version in order for SQL Server 2014 to play nicely with Visual Studio (I would love to be contradicted on this though!).

Comment: But you don't need to upgrade to a new version of VS, just use the VS2012 IDE to access SSDT - if that makes a difference.